# How to find limits of integration when converting to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm specifically struggling on finding the integration bounds for $\theta$ as usually the bounds for the radius are clear to me. For example, for the problem

$\int\limits_{D} \log(x^2 + y^2) \, dA$ where D = $\{(x,y) \mid a^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq b^2\}$, I got this far:

$\int_{b}^{a} \int_{\theta} r \log(r^2) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \, \mathrm{d}r
$

However I cannot figure out what the limits of $\theta$ are, as I simply assumed anytime I saw the equation of a circle ($x^2+y^2$) we would be referring to the whole circle i.e from $0$ to $2\pi$, however that seems to be wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: The integral over $r$ should be $\int_a^b$. Try to draw a picture of the domain $D$, it is an annulus. Each point of $D$ can be written as $x=r \cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$ where $r$ runs from $a$ to $b$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the line connecting the point $(x,y)$ to the origin and the positive $x$-axis. To cover the whole domain, you can let $\theta$ run in an interval of length $2\pi$, e.g. over $[-\pi, \pi[$ (or over $[0,2\pi[.$)

Comment: "...we would be referring to the whole circle i.e from $0$ to $2\pi$, however that seems to be wrong" : Please edit your posting to explain, as carefully as you can, why this seems to be wrong.  Please respond directly in the posting; please do not respond in the comments.